# Is there a way to automate loading csv files in Paraview?

Tags: csv, paraview

I am using Paraview to display well log information stored in csv files.

Upon loading the csv data file and adding the "Table to Points" filter, I manually specify which columns should be used for the **X Column**, **Y Column** and **Z Column** (*e.g.* I am using a column called "Easting" for the "X Column").

Is there a way to automate this step? Maybe some kind of configuration file that could be fed into Paraview to indicate the column mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python macro to do that. Macros in ParaView are python script you can trigger from the toolbar.

You can use this one to create and configure a TableToPoints filter (with modif according to your column names):

```py
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

# create a new 'Table To Points'
tableToPoints1 = TableToPoints(registrationName='TableToPoints1')

# configure column names
tableToPoints1.XColumn = 'y1'
tableToPoints1.YColumn = 'y2'
tableToPoints1.ZColumn = 'y26'

# get active view
spreadSheetView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('SpreadSheetView')

# show data in view
tableToPoints1Display = Show(tableToPoints1, spreadSheetView1, 'SpreadSheetRepresentation')

# hide data in view
Hide(sineWavescsv, spreadSheetView1)

# update the view to ensure updated data information
spreadSheetView1.Update()
```

Store it on your disk and go to menu `Macros / Import new macro`

Note that you can easily create your own with the Python Trace:

1. menu `Tools / Start Trace` (with default options)
2. perform the actions you want to replay later (load file, create filters, edit color map, ...)
3. `Tools / Stop Trace`. It opens an editor with python code, you can save it as a macro.
4. The macro is a new button in the toolbar.

Comment: Your answer hits the spot! Thanks, Nico.